# SMTP Mailgun Throwing Error with Mastodon

Tags: smtp

I'm currently trying to run a mastodon server I've installed everything correctly and I haven't gotten an error till now

I'm setting up my SMTP this is the info I've put in

`SMTP server: smtp.mailgun.org
SMTP username:  mastodon@notifications.example.com
SMTP password:
SMTP authentication: plain
SMTP OpenSSL verify mode: peer`

Then when I try to send a test e-mail it throws this error

`E-mail could not be sent with this configuration, try again.
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)`

Comment: Just ran into this; trying to sort out the issue now...

Comment: I'm assuming you replaced all the domain info and that stuff has been verified, right?  I'm wondering about the authentication / verification modes used here

Answer (score 0):

Ahh!  So someone just pointed out on this thread (https://mastodon.social/@slackz/99772551531768277) that authentication `SMTP_AUTH_METHOD` and `SMTP_OPENSSL_VERIFY_MODE` should be commented out in the config.  The mastodon:setup rake task automatically adds them (gonna look into making a PR to change that), but if you:

- comment out the two lines in `.env.production` with the above env variables
- ensure all your mailgun account records are verified, that you can send email with a curl command they supply on their site
- restart the mastodon processes:

  - `sudo systemctl restart mastodon-*`

Opened an issue about the behavior here:
https://github.com/tootsuite/mastodon/issues/6975